primary constructor parameter is not a property?
Kotlin docs call primary constructor parameters class properties but apparently they are not. What are they?
class A constructor (name: String) {
  fun greet() { println("hello $name") }
}



does not compile. name is an unresolved reference, but
class A constructor (val name: String) {
  fun greet() { println("hello $name") }
}


does. What's the difference aside from val?

class A constructor (name: String) {
  val fullname = "Mr. $name".
  fun greet() { println("hello $fullname") }
}


compiles. I can refer to name here when I construct fullname. And while name is apparently not a property, fullname is.  I can even say A("ken").fullname outside the class.
So what exactly is name without the val since I can still refer to it in some expressions, just not all.
Kotlin newbie but decades writing C++ and python. Thanks for any clarification. I've not found anything online that documents Kotlin as well as kotlinlang.org and I'm already struggling with their docs.

I assume you've read their doc page on classes and constructors - which I feel answers all of your questions - can you edit your question to include a quote from their docs which you're having trouble following?

I quote .."The primary constructor initializes a class instance and its properties in the class header" right after it displays the code "class Person (name:String)".  A class header was previously defined as anything between the class name and its body.  So 'name' is a property is how I would read it.

The "and its properties" part refers to properties/fields declared in the class below that constructor line. This is made explicit a few lines down where it says "Kotlin has a concise syntax for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor:" where it introduces the val and var keywords for ctor parameters.

They're simply constructor parameters.  They can be used in any code that runs as part of constructing an instance, which includes initialisers and init blocks.
For example:
class MyClass(param1: Int) {
    val someProperty = param1 * 2

    init {
        println("param1 was $param1")
    }
}

(Note that the constructor keyword is optional for the primary constructor; it's usually omitted unless e.g. you need to annotate it.)
As you demonstrate, they're like any other method parameters and don't exist after the constructor has finished, so you can't refer to them elsewhere.
Adding val (or var) is syntactic sugar which also creates a property with the same name, initialised to the same value.
So:
class MyClass(val param1: Int)

Is roughly shorthand for:
class MyClass(param1: Int) {
    val param1: Int = param1
}

This is discussed (though maybe not clearly enough) in the Kotlin docs.
FWIW, I learned Kotlin from the book Kotlin In Action, by some of the Kotlin development team at JetBrains.  I found it excellent — but then I already had extensive experience with Java and some knowledge of Scala, and so many of the ideas were already familiar to me; you might find it harder going without that knowledge, but I'd still recommend taking a look.

Thanks for the "Kotlin in Action". I will take a look.

When you have parameters in the constructor that are not properties they are only accessible during initialization of the class.
val fullname = "Mr. $name".

is fine because this line is executed during initialization.
fun greet() { println("hello $name") }

This is not fine because name is accessed whenever you call greet(), not during the initialization.
Another place where to access it would be in init blocks. For example like this.
class A constructor (name: String) {

    init {
        println(name)
    }
}

During initialization of a class it goes through the class from top to bottom doing all variable initializations and init blocks.
Example
fun main() {
   A("hi")
}

class A constructor (name: String) {
    var test: String = "test"
    init {
        println(test)
        //println(test2) this is not possible because test is defined below this block
        println(name)
        test = "newValue $name"
    }

    var test2: String = "test2"

    init {
        println(test)
        println(test2)
    }
}

Output
test
hi
newValue hi
test2


Thank you. Your first sentence says it all. Wish the kotlin docs were as explicit.

If you compare, kotlin to java like constructing objects, the difference should be clear:
class A constructor (name: String) {}

public class A {
    public A (String name) {}
}

name in that case, is just a parameter of the constructor.
class A constructor (val name: String) {}

public class A {
    private String name; 

    public A (String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}

name in that case, is a property of an Instance of A. The dependency is injected via the constructor. name is immutable.
You must consider, that under the hood, kotlin is calling a getter, or setter, when calling the property of an instance. In that case, kotlin is provided with a wide set of tools, to make their code much more readable, that java.
You could override name's getter, as follows:
class A  {
    
    val name: String
        get() = field

    constructor(name: String) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html
